# Fuse box coming off of fuse at meter socket

Tags: electrical, wiring

House built in the 50’s has an old fuse box that is being used to power lights and outlets in one of the barns on the property. The fuse box in this barn is fed from a 60 amp breaker at the meter. The meter socket was installed 2 years ago. The breaker box at the meter has a 100amp breaker for my house, and a 60amp breaker to the barn. 
My question(s) is can I replace the fuse box with a load center? And is this even considered a subpanel since it does not come off of the main panel in the house?
Thanks in advance.

[image: Breaker at Meter]

[image]

[image: Fuse Box in Barn]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the meter on a pole, at the house, or at the barn?  Are the feeders from the meter box to the house and barn panels 3-wire or 4-wire?  Can you provide photos of the inside of the fuse box (with the breaker at the meter off, of course)?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I will Take the pictures as soon as I am home and post them. Thank you again.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel - I have several barns on the property and the meter is on a pole between all the barns and the house. It it’s probably 3’ from the barn with the fuse box that I have the questions about. The feeders appear to be two wire. I have attached the photos you requested. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I apologize I thought I could just copy and paste the photos here but apparently I cannot, and I'm having trouble finding any way to attach the photos.

Comment: The panel on the pole is actually your main panel the one in the house and barns are sub panels of this panel. Can you update it sure it will make resetting a circuit easier and safer since many times the wrong size fuse is used with a breaker just turn it off all the way then back on but you already know that. Just to recap the breakers at the pole are the mains and the ones in the house and barn are sub panels.

Comment: @Steelermako -- you should be able to hit "edit" in the "share edit ..." under your post on the left and then use the button that looks like a mountain-and-sun painting to add the photos to it

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I have attached the photos you requested, they are attached to the original post.  The meter appears to be grounded at the pole as well.  Ed - explained that all my breakers and fuseboxes are considered subpanels of the main at the pole.  I didn't mention in my original post that the 60 amp breaker is a double pole breaker if that makes any difference in your answer.   If I were in change the fusebox for a load center would I need to bond the ground to the box in this case or not?

Comment: Bond the grounding bar to the box I meant.

Comment: Can you post photos showing where the wires exit the main panel and enter the barn subpanel?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I added the two pictures you asked for.  Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Can you tell if those are individual wires in conduit I'm seeing there, or some sort of direct buried cable instead?

Comment: The pipe those black-black-yellow feeder  wires are going down.  Is that metal conduit?  Also the yellow wire really ought to be taped white; yellow is a hot color.  White or gray are the only neutral colors.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -  They are all individual wires in conduit.

Comment: @Harper -  the pipe is black-black-yellow feeder wares are going down is 1 1/4" rigid schedule 40 pvc conduit all the way to the barn which is about 3' away from the meter.  Does the material of the conduit change anything I would have to do to install a subpanel?  Just curious.

Comment: Since there is no ground wire coming to the current fuse box from the breaker at the meter, would I need to run a ground wire to properly repace this fusebox with a new subpanel or would grounding rods suffice?

Comment: Yes,  you'd need to run ground wires, but since it's all in conduit, that should be a straightforward task.  You'll also need ground rods at all locations including the pole.  Unless you can talk your AHJ out of all this.

Comment: @Harper - thank you very much for the help.  Lastly, the ground that is shown in the breaker box at the pole goes directly into the ground at the pole. Will I still need a ground rod at the pole?  Also should the ground wire I will run to the subpanel should be bound to new subpanel? I’ve seen yes and no to this question in various locations. Again thank you for all your help to everyone that commented here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You'll need to stuff a ground wire down that conduit first

The first order of business in this job is to get a ground wire down that conduit to the barn.  You'll need several feet of 8AWG bare stranded copper for this, with one end going to the combination N/G bar in the pole panel, and the other end left hanging in the barn panel for now. (You'll also want to turn the main breaker at the pole off while doing this pull.)  Don't worry about conduit fill, by the way: a 1.25" Schedule 40 PVC conduit supplies about twice as much fill as you'll need for everything here.

### Then you can replace the barn panel with something modern

Once you have a ground wire in the conduit and hooked up to the main panel, you can then replace the subpanel in the barn with a modern breaker box.  I recommend a 100A, 24-space, main breaker panel as a *minimum* for this application; the main breaker here simply serves as a local shutoff means for power to the barn, so it can be larger than the feeder breaker without causing any issues, and slots are cheap to buy now when you're changing the panel out *anyway* but rather expensive to add later.  Also, make sure to fit the panel with separate ground bars if it doesn't come with them fitted from the factory, and to *pull* the (usually green) bonding screw from the panel's neutral assembly so that it's configured properly as a subpanel.

### And the barn will need ground rods, too

While you're working on the barn, you'll need to drive a couple of 8' ground rods 8' apart and use more of that 8AWG bare copper to connect both ground rods to the barn subpanel.  This takes care of the other side of grounding the barn; the ground *wire* to the main panel returns wayward *utility* electricity back to the *utility*, while the ground *rods* return wayward *natural* electricity (such as lightning-induced transients or even just static charges) back to terra firma.

### Torque matters!

One more thing is that you'll want to use an inch-pound torque wrench and/or torque screwdriver when making up the lug connections on breakers and loadcenters so that you tighten the screws to the labeled specification torques; this is required by 2017 NEC 110.14(D), and is a good idea anyway lest a bad connection in your electrical system [slow your roll](https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2010/07/16/the-difference-between-success-and-failure-how-a-torque-wrench-improves-system-reliability/).

Comment: that’s exactly the info I was looking for. Thank you. I have purchased the ground wire and the replacement panel only to find that the feeder wires were left with too little excess to reach the new connection points.  Is there a legitimate way to splice these to extend them Of should I just remove them and run new cables?  It’s only approx 15 feet in distance accounting for underground conduit length  from barn to meter at pole.

Comment: @Steelermako you can use some insulated mechanical lugs ("Polaris connectors") to splice some extra wire onto the feeder, although for that short of a run, it might be cheaper to simply replace them.  Also, we thank people around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)

Comment: I think I upvoted and accepted your answer. I hope I did anyway - I’m new here. I haven’t been able to find #8 bare stranded locally - I live in the sticks would #8 green insulated be acceptable? Also since I will be taking your advise to replace the cable from the pole/panel instead of splicing. #4 copper is the correct cable for this I believe. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: @Steelermako -- #4 *aluminum* is fine for 60A when landing on 75degC lugs such as in your scenario here, and #8 green THHN will work for the ground wire (I just prefer bare as it uses less fill).